# $table.floatThead() not recognized as a function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to froze the `thead` table on the top of the screen when scrolling the table by using the jquery `floatThead()` function. 
I'm referencing the jquery to the page but it is not working when I press the f12 key there is an X saying "floatThead is not a function".
this is the jquery code:

```
$(function () {
    var $table = $('table.tableTop');
    $table.floatThead();
});
```

and this is the html:

```
<table class="tableTop">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>.....
```

this is the error:
[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

`floatThead()` is not a part of inbuilt jQuery Plugin. It comes when you include jquery.floatThead table header plugin in your project. Please check if it is already included from [here](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your HTML, ***before*** you run your script. This loads the plugin from a CDN (easiest way).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/floatthead/2.2.3/jquery.floatThead.min.js"></script>
```

Then run your script (NOTE: you ***MUST*** use a JQuery selector, not a regular JavaScript selector):

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  <!-- Select the table with JQuery, NOT regular JavaScript -->
  var $table = $('table.tableTop');
  
  <!-- Run the plugin's function! -->
  $table.floatThead();
</script>
```

Check out the below code snippet for a fully-working example:

```js
<!-- This WILL work! -->
console.log("Attempt 1, using $ variable and JQuery selector WILL work!");
var $tbl = $("#myTable");
$tbl.floatThead();

<!-- This will NOT work -->
console.log("Attempt 2, with normal variable will NOT work!");
var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
tbl.floatThead();

<!-- This WILL NOT work either -->
console.log("Attempt 3, with $ in front of variable will NOT work either!");
var $tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
$tbl.floatThead();
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 1rem;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  background: #eee;
}

thead {
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

tfoot {
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
}

body {
  font: 110%/1.4 system-ui;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10rem 2rem 50rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />

</head>

<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem doloribus quibusdam nostrum quo tempore veritatis magnam similique nisi quis enim soluta, cupiditate officiis. Voluptate eligendi dolor earum ipsam obcaecati? Placeat.</p>

  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Footer</th>
        <th>Footer</th>
        <th>Footer</th>
        <th>Footer</th>
        <th>Footer</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Row Header</th>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row Header</th>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row Header</th>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row Header</th>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row Header</th>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row Header</th>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row Header</th>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row Header</th>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row Header</th>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row Header</th>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
        <td>Cell Data</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem doloribus quibusdam nostrum quo tempore veritatis magnam similique nisi quis enim soluta, cupiditate officiis. Voluptate eligendi dolor earum ipsam obcaecati? Placeat.</p>

  <!-- Load JQuery first -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Then load floatThead JQuery plugin -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/floatthead/2.2.2/jquery.floatThead.min.js" integrity="sha512-QhaSMfyPHtKHbg7e//C6Y/nmpflIM9PgmhZ/TR+BcbRaR9eYXzZRfuK5D9pnVlp+J5zWXu5ckVzX4ycOQy/jZA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the plugin jquery.floatThead.js
Here you can see the details:
http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/